# Building neo4j-client for the Windows platform

Tags: neo4j, libneo4j-client

I want to build the neo4j-client (C source code) on the Windows platform.  The github project by Chris Leishman has some good documentation on it, but it appears to be Linux/UNIX only.  I am curious to know if anyone has built this library on Windows and if there is a way to get that source code or instructions on how to modify the standard source to build on Windows.

Thanks!

Comment: It'd probably be best to post a specific issue to the [neo4j-client](https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client) repo and ask the author. Not really a fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: Another option is to join the Neo4j-Users Slack and ask on the #Drivers channel

Comment: Since we're talking about improving neo4j-client, it's best to raise this as an issue in the [github repo](https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client), and we can discuss what needs to be done there! Thanks for the interest!

Comment: For others visiting this issue, as of Aug 2016, Windows support is at the top of the [neo4j-client TODO list](https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client/wiki/TODO)